# Skip login/registration in magento one page checkout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I have only one product on my site, so I don't want the hassle of login/register for my users on onepage checkout. Hence I want my onepage checkout to skip and hide login/registration and directly take every checkout as guest checkout. I'm a new magento developer so have very limited knowledge about blocks, models, etc.

Below is the article which shows how it can be done, but I cannot implement it
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-login-step/

Can anyone just help me with the paths I need to create this files. I have asked the same question on magento stackexchange but no one replies there

Comment: You need to tell more about your issue, what is blocking you from following the tutorial, what error are you having, what don't you know from the tutorial, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am new magento developer so don't know how play with model, block etc. which the tutorial in my question did not explained clearly. Followed [this tutorial](http://www.magentothem.com/archives/3127) to achieve this in 3 simple steps. Just there's a slide change due to the intro of persistent directory in /template. In step 2, the path you need to edit is template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml and you are done!